# Append files fails intermittently

Tags: perl

I am using the script below to append two files, and it intermittently fails to append with no error output.

```
(my $file1, my $file2) = @ARGV;

open(FILE1, ">>$file1");
open(FILE2, "<$file2");

while ( <FILE2> ) {
    print FILE1 $_;
}

close(FILE2);
close(FILE1);
```

Is there any issue with above code?

Comment: what error you are facing from your code??

Comment: No error here. But: (1) Always check: `open my $fh, '>>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";`  (the [`$!`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$!) is critical, that will show you the actual error if any)  (2) Do you have `use warnings;` at the beginning?

Comment: How does it "_fail to append_" and how "_intermittently_" does it do that -- a line here or there in a file, or no append at all for a file among many?

Comment: Btw, you normally say `my ($v1, $v2,...)`, not `(my $v1, my $v2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary issue with your code is that it includes a number of operations that might fail but you are not checking for errors, so in the event of a failure the program will silently try to carry on.

The three functions in your code which could potentially fail are `open`, `print` and `close`.  In each case, the function will return a true value on success or in the event of failure, will return a false value and also will store the failure message in the special global variable `$!`.

You have written:

```
open(FILE1,">>$file1");
```

That would be better written as:

```
open(my $out, '>>', $file1) || die "open(>>$file1): $!";
```

Or you can use the lower precedence `or` operator and skip the parentheses:

```
open my $out, '>>', $file1 or die "open(>>$file1): $!";
```

You could simply call `die $!` but that will give you an error message like `Permission denied` and won't tell you which operation failed (although `die` will add the line number where the failure occurred).  Sometimes the failure is due to the fact that the variable containing the filename has something unexpected in it - so it's a good habit to print that out as well.

Your code includes some rather old style so I replaced the old style `FILE1` global with the lexically scoped `$out`.  I also used the 3-argument form of open which is a better idea from a security perspective.

The `print` calls could also fail (e.g.: if your disk filled up).  This is less likely and checking the return value of `print` is often overlooked.  The `close` call could also fail (e.g.: the output buffer might not get flushed until you close the filehandle and then something like a disk full condition could trigger a failure).

Remembering to add `or die "... $!"` on the end of all your I/O function calls is a bit tedious, so a better approach is to add the `autodie` pragma to the boiler plate at the start of your script.  Then you can omit the explicit error checks and the `autodie` module will generate messages for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my($file1,  $file2) = @ARGV;
open my $out, '>>',  $file1;
open my $in,  '<',   $file2;
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

A typical message from autodie might be:

```
Can't open '/etc/shadow' for reading: 'Permission denied' at ./ptst.pl line 8
```

This tells you which operation failed, what the arguments were and the reason for the failure.  So by using `autodie` you get great error messages for less effort.

Comment: thanks for this detailed explanation, will add this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version to get an error message:

```
open(FILE1,">>", $file1) or die $!;
open(FILE2, "<", $file2) or die $!;
```

Comment: this throws message if the files do not open up?

Comment: @Sriyad what message do you have?

Comment: I'd suggest to also show lexical filehandles and mention `use warnings;`, once you are at it